# Using Rolle’s Theorem, prove that between any two roots of $f(x)=1-e^x\sin(x)$ there exists at least one root of $g(x)=1+e^x\cos(x)$.

Tags: real-analysis

I have this question for my real analysis assignment that I have spent way too much time on. Someone please help me with it.

Consider the continuous functions $f : \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$, $f (x) = 1 − e^x\sin(x)$ and $g : \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$, $g(x) = 1 + e^x\cos(x)$.

Using Rolle’s Theorem, prove that between any two roots of $f$ there exists at least one root of $g$. Remember that, a root of f is a point $x$ in the domain of $f$ such that $f(x) = 0$.

Comment: Perhaps the fact that $g(x)=2-f(x)$ for all $x$ might be useful?

Comment: nah not really man, it's sin for f and cos for g.

Comment: Sorry, my bad..

Comment: thanks for trying man, I did have the same mistake when I first start to solve this question too

Comment: Another try - roots of $f$ are the same as roots of $\exp(-x)-\sin x$.

Answer (score 2):

Suppose $ f(x)=1-e^x\sin x = 0.$ Then $e^{-x} - \sin x =0.$ So if $a<b$ are roots of $f(x),$ then $a,b$ are roots of $e^{-x} - \sin x.$ By Rolle, the derivative of $e^{-x}- \sin x,$ which is $-e^{-x}-\cos x,$ is $0$ at some $c\in (a,b).$ But $-e^{-c}-\cos c=0$ implies $e^c\cos c + 1=0,$ which is the same as saying $g(c)=0.$

Answer (score -1):

http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=plot+1-(e%5Ex)sin(x)

Looking at the graphs of both f and g. Go to your table on your calculator and as x increases the corresponding y values will go from huge negative to huge positive values very quick and each time there will be a root apparent on the graph.  Rolle's Theorem says that between these zeros there are points where the tangent line has a slope of zero.  That is to say that the derivative of each function will exist at f'(c) for any points a and b.  Choose starting points between at least two roots of f and you'll find at least one root of g due to the parity of the functions.