# Rolle's theorem on $e^x\sin x-1=0$

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, functions, roots, rolles-theorem

> Prove that between any two real roots of the equation $e^x\sin x-1=0$ the equation $e^x\cos x+1=0$ has at least one root.

My attempts:

By Rolle's theorem, the derivative of $e^x\sin x-1=0$ has at least one root between the roots $(\text{let}\ a,b)$ of $e^x\sin x-1=0$

$$f'(x)=e^x\sin x +e^x\cos x=\overbrace{\underbrace{(e^x\sin x-1)}_{2). \text{ no root in}\ (a,b)} +\underbrace{(e^x\cos x+1)}_{1,2\implies\text{ no root in}\ (a,b)}}^{\text{1). at least one root in}\ (a,b)}=0,\ x\in(a,b)$$

I found alternative proof of this [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1786502/296971), but please don't mark this as duplicate as I want to know what's the wrong with what is tried.

Comment: By Rolle's, there is a $c \in (a,b) \colon f'(c) = 0$. If $\mathrm e^c \sin(c) =1$, then we are done. What if $\mathrm e^c \sin(c) -1 \neq 0$?

Answer (score 1):

Refer to the graph:

$\hspace{2cm}$[image]

You are mixing up the points $c$ with $d$.

> By Rolle's theorem, the derivative of $e^x\sin x−1=0$ has at least one root between the roots (let $a,b$) of $e^x\sin x−1=0$.

True, let's call this point $d\in (a,b)$, then:
$$f'(d)=e^d\sin d +e^d\cos d=(\underbrace{e^d\sin d-1}_{\ne 0})+(\underbrace{e^d\cos d+1}_{\ne 0})=0$$
However, the equation $e^x\cos x+1=0$ may (in fact, it does) have its root at the point $c\in (a,b)$, $c\ne d$.
So, the above condition must look like:
$$f'(d)=e^d\sin d +e^d\cos d=\\
(\underbrace{e^d\sin d+e^d\cos d-e^c\cos c-1}_{= 0})+(\underbrace{e^c\cos c+1}_{= 0})=0.$$
However, the equality of the first term to zero must be proved.

Note that the solution by zhw given in the [link](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1786298/using-rolle-s-theorem-prove-that-between-any-two-roots-of-fx-1-ex-sinx-t/1786502#1786502) is efficient. Indeed, note how skillfully the exponential and sine functions are separated:
$$f(x)=1-e^x\sin x = 0 \iff e^x\sin x=1 \iff \\
\sin x=e^{-x} \iff e^{-x}-\sin x=0.$$

Answer (score 0):

$$f'(x)=e^x\sin x +e^x\cos x=\overbrace{\underbrace{(e^x\sin x-1)}_{2). \text{ no root in}\ (a,b)} +\underbrace{(e^x\cos x+1)}_{1,2\implies\text{ no root in}\ (a,b)}}^{\text{1). at least one root in}\ (a,b)}=0,\ x\in(a,b)$$

$$\text{1). at least one root in}\ (a,b)$$

$$\text{2). no root in}\ (a,b)$$

the whole expression has one root in $(a,b)$

the first expression has no root in $(a,b)$

then how will you get that at least one root that you are claiming for the whole expression.

So the 2nd expression gives us that root thus $$1,2\implies\text{ at least one  root in}\ (a,b)$$